# JavaScript Date creation fails in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, date

i do have a misfunction with JavaScript date creation in IE.
The following does work in any Browser but the IE. IE seems to create a random date in 2014
Do you have any idea, why it does fail?

```
 var date = new Date();
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
 var expires = date.toGMTString();
```

Comment: I set days = 45 and tried it in IE8 and it works.

Comment: look at CBroe _not every day is 86400 seconds long (DST, remember?)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from that I can not recreate your issue, adding 24 * 60 * 60 seconds to a timestamp to advance the days is just *wrong* – not every day is 86400 seconds long (DST, remember?).

Instead, you should just set the days of the date object to current value plus x, it will be converted to the right date automatically:

```
var date = new Date(), daysToAdd = 45;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + daysToAdd);
var expires = date.toGMTString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of IE, it is possible that the ECMAscript5 standard is not yet implemented which is the standard that defines date objects.

Take a look here.... [javascript date object issue in Safari and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11253351/javascript-date-object-issue-in-safari-and-ie)

Comment: yes, but i do create a new date with the browser itself - without transferiing a manual date object as mentioned behind the link  ;(