# Angularjs orderBy filter does not filter dates correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a problem with angularjs orderBy filter. I am trying to sort a list of items by date ascending or descending.

This is how my list looks like

```
...
<li ng-repeat="issue in content | myStatusFilter : selectedStatuses | orderBy : 'date' : selectedOption" class="toggle-list__row">
    <issue data="issue" />
</li>
...
```

Content is an array and each issue in content has a date and this date is saved as string. When the selectedOption is true this is what I get

1. Issue 3 - 31.01.2015
2. Issue 2 - 21.05.2015
3. Issue 4 - 10.06.2015
4. Issue 1 - 04.05.2014 -> should be first in the list actually

and when the selectedOption is false this is the output

1. Issue 1 - 04.05.2014 - should be the last one
2. Issue 4 - 10.06.2015
3. Issue 2 - 21.05.2015
4. Issue 3 - 31.01.2015

Could you please help me and tell me where is the mistake and how can I fix this issue.

Thx in advance

Comment: Can't you change your date format for year first, then month, then day?

Comment: are your dates actual `Date` objects?

Comment: "by date ascending and descending." At the same time? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @sal niro Dates are saved as string dd.MM.yyyy.

Comment: @Pureferret I am having a slecet where you can pick asc or desc order and because of that I have selectedOption in the filter as you can see in code and yes, the issues sould be ordered ascending or descending

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your dates are strings, not proper javascript date objects.  Since you say you can't fix this on the server, you can atleast fix this in the controller or angular service.

Wherever you get your object that contains dates, loop through the objects and turn them into actual dates, like:

```
$http.get('something')
     .then(function(result) {
         result.forEach(function(item) {
            item.date = new Date(item.date.replace( /(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3")
         });
     });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a function to the order by filter. In that function convert your string into a date:

```
$scope.myDateOrderFunction = function(item) {
   var parts = item.date.split('.');
   return new Date(parts[2], parts[1], parts[0]);
};
```

and then you can call it from the view:

```
<li ng-repeat="issue in content | myStatusFilter : selectedStatuses | orderBy : myDateOrderFunction : selectedOption" class="toggle-list__row">
    <issue data="issue" />
</li>
```

Comment: Good idea in parsing out the existing dates!

Comment: Can someone conver this exact using filter from controller end ? somewhat like: $filter('orderBy')( converToDate, , )

Answer (score 1):

Your dates are sorted *alphabetically*, either make them a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object or store them as 'yyyy.mm.dd'

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hobeLtL3/) (n.b. not originally written by me, but I have updated it)

```
<div ng-app>
      <div ng:controller="Main">
      <div ng:repeat="item in items | orderBy:'date'">{{$index}}: {{item.date | date}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {date: new Date('12/23/2013')},
        {date: new Date('12/23/2011')},
        {date: new Date('12/23/2010')},
        {date: new Date('12/23/2015')}
    ];
}
```

If your dates come form the backend, you need to write a service/factory to get these, then you'll have something like `$scope.issues = IssueService.getIssues()`. Which needs to return an array.

Comment: Is it possible to change date format in html template, you can see above in  `<li></li>` where the other filters are or do I have to write a custom filter for that?

Comment: and the problem is that I get these date values from backend and I cannot change them in the response array

Comment: @amsalk If you have further problems, searching Stack overflow can help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22395280/1075247

Comment: I already have that and it works fine, however I thought that it would be complicated to parse strings to `Date` objects in the json array which comes from the backend. Joao offered a nice solution and I would like to thank you also for your effort.