# How do I format Angular Material's md-datepicker for Django REST Framework?

Tags: angularjs, django, datepicker, django-rest-framework, material-design

***EDITED the original question after further research.***

Using Angular Material, I have a relatively simple form inside an `$mdDialog` that makes a POST request to a Django REST Framework endpoint. **All the data submits just fine except that from the `md-datepicker` element.**

I can pick a date, bind it to a variable in my controller, and even display the data in real-time (just below `md-datepicker`) w/ Angular templating. That output suggests that the selected date is just a standardized date string:

`"2015-11-27T06:00:00.000Z"`

But on submit, what gets sent as form data is a different longform string:

```
parsed: Fri Nov 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)
raw: Fri+Nov+20+2015+00%3A00%3A00+GMT-0600+(Central+Standard+Time)
```

This causes Django REST Framework to throw up a Bad Request exception since that format isn't listed in my settings.py as acceptable. I need it either format the `md-datepicker` output to `MM-DD-YYYYThh:mm:ss.uuuuuuZ`, or specify another format in my settings.py, which currently has those values:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': ('%m-%d-%YT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'),
    'DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS': ('%m-%d-%YT%H:%M:%S.%fZ', '$m-%d-$y')
}
```

**How do I format an `md-datepicker` POST value to an output Django REST Framework can understand?** I've checked out the following threads which call for updating the `.parseDate` and `.formatDate` methods in `$mdDateLocaleProvider` but that doesn't change the value that eventually gets injected into my post request:

[Change format of md-datepicker in Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566416/change-format-of-md-datepicker-in-angular-material)

Any help appreciated - relatively new to Angular. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

After more research, I figured it out. Posting the answer in case anyone else encounters this issue.

Basically, `md-datepicker` stores a JavaScript Date object by default. Trying to send the Date object as-is resulted in the longform string in POST that Django REST Framework couldn't interpret. Luckily, JS Date objects have a built-in method for generating an ISO-compliant string, which DRF has no problem with. In my controller, I changed the form submission function, using the `.toISOString()` method to convert the JS object, then making my POST request:

```
$scope.submitClient = function (data) {
    data.md_date = data.md_date.toISOString();
    $.post({
            url: '/clients/',
            data: data
    })
}
```