# AngularJS - Injection in config

Tags: angularjs

In my app I need to inject "dateFilter" in the `config` block. I know I can't do it like this:

```
.config(function(dateFilter){})
```

Since `dateFilter` is not a provider or a constant, it's not available during `config`.

However, after some research, I made it work by using the following in the `config`:

```
angular.injector(["ng"]).get('dateFilter')('2014-01-01','yyyy/MM/dd');
```

Doesn't this mean that I can get anything during `config`? Then what's the point making only `providers` and `constants` injectable during `config`? Is it bad to do something like `angular.injector(["ng"]).get('dateFilter')` during `config`?

Comment: Rarely need to do this and chances are you don't need to either but you haven't shown or explained why you need it directly in config. Note that you can inject locals into routing resolves if that has anything to do with use case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566416/change-format-of-md-datepicker-in-angular-material The answer here is what I want to do. I don't use moment.j s so I use dateFilter instead.

Comment: Can do that in `run()` block instead where you can inject locals

Comment: `$mdDateLocaleProvider` isn't available at `run` block.

Comment: Wow it works. It's not in the docs. How do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.injector` shouldn't be used in production, unless the circumstances are really exotic (i.e. almost never). It creates a new injector instance and introduces some overhead. Conventional Angular DI is good for its testability, while `angular.injector` turns a part of the application into untestable piece of code. Always reuse current injector inside the app, if possible (i.e. almost always).

Usually 'how to use service instance in config block' type of questions indicates an XY problem. The fact that Angular uses `config` to configure service providers that thereafter will create service instances (chicken-egg dilemma) suggests that the application should be refactored to respect Angular life cycle.

However, built-in filters are stateless helper functions, and their use in config phase is relatively harmless. [`dateFilter` service is defined by `$filterProvider`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.6/src/ng/filter.js#L156), and `$filterProvider` should be injected to get to `dateFilterProvider`. The problem is that `dateFilter` [depends on `$locale` service](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.6/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L576), which wasn't instantiated yet. `$locale` is constant (in broad sense) that doesn't depend on other services, so it has to be instantiated too.

```
angular.module('...', [
  'ngLocale' // if used, should be loaded in this module
])
.config(($filterProvider, $localeProvider, $provide, $injector) => {
  var $locale = $injector.invoke($localeProvider.$get);
  var dateFilterProvider = $injector.get('dateFilterProvider')
  var dateFilter =  $injector.invoke(dateFilterProvider.$get, { $locale: $locale });

  $provide.constant('dateHelper', dateFilter);
})
```

This is a hack should be taken into account in tests (`dateHelper` service should superficially tested) but is relatively trouble-free and idiomatic.

Comment: So `angular.injector` creates a new instance, but `$injector` reuses the current instance? So it's fine to use `$injector` as in your example?

Comment: Yes. Notice that you can't do $injector.get() to get service instance in config, so $injector.invoke should be invoked with $get function, this does the trick.

Comment: Do I need this line `$provide.constant('dateHelper', dateFilter);`? I can just use `dateFilter` after `var dateFilter =  $injector.invoke(dateFilterProvider.$get, { $locale: $locale });`, right?

Comment: Not really, but this will improve testability, and tests are important here (if Angular will change the way $filter deals with built-in filters, the app will be screwed with no explanation). Again, this may be XY problem, and you may not need to do this in `config`.

Answer (score 0):

you cant inject services in config only provides but you can do it in app.run here's the calling order:

1. app.config() //only provides can be injected
2. app.run()    //services can be injected
3. directive's compile functions (if they are found in the dom)
4. app.controller()
5. directive's link functions (again, if found)