# Angular datepicker difference between onChange and onInput

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I've got a internationalization difference with angular datepicker between onChange and onInput events:

Here my code:

In my module, i provide the `fr` format to datepicker like this:

```
providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'fr-FR'
    }
],
```

So the return date format expected is: `dd/mm/yyyy` as french format.
This work well when i've pick a date with the calendar. But if I enter directly by date in the input i still have a `us` format `mm/dd/yyyy` in return.

Maybe i missing something but i don't see where in the angular material documentation this case is precise.

Any help will be appreciated. Thx

Edit: I provide a [stackbliz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-6ugz21) to show my problem.

Comment: Are you manually entering `mm/dd/yyyy` and expecting it to change to `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: I enter a date in `dd/mm/yyyy`, all my flow use this pattern. But when a user enter a date directly, datepicker convert it to `mm/dd/yyyy`, but by selecting the date with the calendar, it keep the good fomat

Comment: See [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566416/change-format-of-md-datepicker-in-angular-material#answer-34654424)

Comment: Here's it [implemented](https://codepen.io/vinays84/pen/bYNLvv)