# How to change input date format?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, input

JS:

`$scope.getDate = new Date();`

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <input type="date" ng-model="getDate" class="form-control input-sm">
</div>
```

Result : `10/19/2015` (in Chrome)

It's easy to not use ng-model. `{{getDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}`. But I need 'yyyy-MM-dd' format in ng-model, not using date filter. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

You can try such way:

```
Date.prototype.myformat = function() {
        var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
        var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
        var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
        return yyyy + "-" + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
      };
var dd = new Date();
$scope.getDate = dd.myformat;
```

result: 2015-10-19

Comment: Thank you mate, thank you! I solved the problem with angular UI :D

Comment: There is no need to call *toString*, particularly as the month and day expressions convert the parameters back to a number again during evaluation. Then `mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]` can be `mm > 9?mm:"0"+mm`, same for day. Or `('0'+mm).slice(-2)`.

Answer (score 0):

JS :`$scope.open = function($event) {
    $scope.status.opened = true;
 };
 $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: 'yy',
    startingDay: 1
 };
 $scope.format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
var app = angular.module('someApp',['ui.bootstrap']);` //app.js

HTML : `<input type="text" class="form-control sm" ng-click="open($event)" datepicker-mode="month" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="getDate" is-open="status.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" current-text="Today" clear-text="Clear" close-text="Close"/>`

[image: result]

Thanks for your comments guys! ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-bind` for binding model to other HTML element with or without filter.

```
<p ng-bind=" getDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"></p>
```