# How to format date and time on AngularJS Datepicker input field?

Tags: angularjs

I have used AngularJS to create a datetime and time input field.
A sample code would be:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="startdate" datetime-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" />
<input type="time" id="starttime" time-format="HH:mm:ss" />
```

The result on client was be:

[image: This is image of the code above]

So the outcome input fields from the client view doesn’t have correct format as I expected. Because I wanted it to be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" but it gave me "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"

You can see on fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/prm739gj/

I want to format the datetime field as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" and time field as ="HH:mm:ss”. Could you help me to get a correct attribute for input field to format date time as I wanted?

Comment: Seems like this might be a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs

Comment: Angular strap has some useful feature to handle date and time in angular,,,u can check it...

Comment: Look like we cannot change the format from the input field, but we can change the format of value which have got from the input field.

Comment: I have try other datepicker, but they all seem to be unable to load within angular control.