# How to format date without using date filter and by using only js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text feild with type equal to text.

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="date"/>
<p>{{date}}</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="date"> // should be able to see date in formatted form here.
```

When i select a date it p tag showing like.

```
2002-05-13T00:00:00
```

i want to show that in proper date format without using another plugin or type="date" because i'm using a plugin with dont have a proper way to format.

How to format the particular date using javascript ?

Comment: You can use http://momentjs.com/docs/ for formating date

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27615392/2460773

Comment: Or any of the [inbuilt date formatting functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: There's no reason to use momentjs when angular has date formatting built in @anomepani

Comment: Refere to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs

Comment: What exactly is "proper date format"? It's unclear quite what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`date`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)** filter

Like this

```
{{date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

Comment: beat me to it! I've got to be faster ;)

Comment: lol . Lucky this time :) @ShannonHochkins

Comment: sorry im not satisfied, i dont want to do it in view side, need to do it in js part

Comment: Please go to the link that i mentioned in my answer @Vispriya