# Angular 1.5 input type time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, input

Ok so I have coming from my object in the following format, "1970-01-01T23:00:00.000Z" and I have a function to a convert it to a normal time in the format of hh:mm. However, I do not know how to format the date while it is two way binded in the following format.

```
<input type="time" ng-model="times.monday.start" >
```

The function I made to format the data is the following:

```
$scope.formatTime = function(dateTime) {
        var time = moment(dateTime).format("hh:mm");
        return time;
    }
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs

Comment: moment does not return a date object... but anyway I am not sure if it will help.