# Change date format in listing

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm new in Angular.

I want to display  db date in 'Sat Mar 10 2001' in this format

How can i put this in my code.

**code sample**

```
<td>{{data.act_date}}<td> //format:mm/dd/yyyy
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27615392/4248328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the angular date filter,

```
 <pre>  {{ dateBirth | date: 'fullDate' }}</pre>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/34j6kzgt/)

Comment: $scope.dateBirth = $scope.data.act_date;

Comment: console.log($scope.data.act_date) i got undefined in console

Comment: can i get team viewer?

Comment: No.its not accessbile

Comment: can you post complete code atleast?

Comment: can you post complete code atleast?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128322/discussion-between-user6721756-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: hi..Can u plz cme to the chat link