# converting date format in angularjs controller

Tags: angularjs

i write the following coding to print the current date time

`$scope.date = new Date();`

and then i print the same using consol.log

```
console.log($scope.date);
```

and it is working fine

> Tue Jan 24 2017 16:36:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

but now i want to change the date format and i want to print like

> 21-12-2016

can anybody help me here?

i used the conversion but i am unable to remember the page or the url of the page right now,

and stuck on this,

before i leave for the home today i thought of solving this issue

Comment: Take a look to the [Angular date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In controller you can do

```
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
```

to change the date format. And in html,

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

use this.

Like

```
$scope.formattedDate =   $filter('date')($scope.currDate, "dd-MM-yyyy");
```

to print same on html

```
{{ currDate | date : "dd-MM-yyyy"}}
```

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date
>   Following formats are supported by angular.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this either in controller or in html page.

```
$scope.date = new Date();
The first one is :
$scope.date =   $filter('date')($scope.date, 'dd-MM-yyyy');

Second one is : 
{{date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Angular date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):

```
{{date | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in-build js libraries functions i.e `getDay()`, `getHours()`, `getMinutes()`, `getMilliseconds()`. This functions will return you the corresponding date's individual components values.

e.g

```
var x = $scope.yourDateModelObj.getHours();
```

Likewise, you can get the date, month, years values.

return an integer value for hours.

Hope that helps