# Format datetime object in Array and display in ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've a function that gets a list of Users. Each individual user has a `last_logged` field which shows the last logged in time in this format `2017-02-04 19:54:47`. What I need to do is display that field on the page in this format `Saturday, February 2, 2017 - 19:54:47`.

Currently the time format is `2017-02-04 19:54:47` (native datetime format)
How can I format it such that it shows `Saturday, February 2, 2017 - 19:54:47`

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Last Login</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.last_login }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date in angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
{{calculateTime(last_login) | date: 'EEEE, MMMM M, yyyy - HH:mm:ss'}}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B9RsQ/39/)

```
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.last_login = "2017-02-04 19:54:47";
  $scope.calculateTime = function(dt) {
    return new Date(dt).getTime();
  }
});
```

Comment: How did you get the "1486218287000" value for 2017-02-04 19:54:47?

Comment: Perfect, exactly what was needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can format a `date` with the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) and the format that you need to get that its

`date:"EEEE',' MMMM d',' yyyy ' - ' HH:mm"`

so you code would look like something like this

```
{{user.last_login  | date:"EEEE',' MMMM d',' yyyy ' - ' HH:mm"}}
```