# Angularjs: How to filter the date

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I want to format it to date format like

> dd-MM-yyyy

The data iam getting from API is as follows

```
 Mon Feb 13 2017 12:30:28 GMT+0000 (UTC)
```

Any help?

Comment: i think you are looking for this :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs

Comment: `ng-bind="date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'"`

Comment: @prakashtank thanks for the response but Its not working

Comment: @RNS you need to first convert your string "Mon Feb 13 2017 12:30:28 GMT+0000 (UTC)" to js date like `var convertDate =new Date("Mon Feb 13 2017 12:30:28 GMT+0000 (UTC)")`, then apply angular default date filter i.e. `{{convertDate | date:"dd-MM-y"}}`

Comment: @amansinghgusain Thanks it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it in `View` or also in `controller`,

**1) Formatting the Date in the View:**

`<p>Date Formatted in view = {{ today | date:"dd-MM-y" }}</p>`

`{{ today | date:"dd-MM-y" }}` is the default date filter of angular.

**2) Formatting the Date in the Controller:**

`$scope.date = $filter('date')($scope.today, "dd-MM-yyyy");`, where you need to inject the `$filter` module of angular.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

<p>Date Formatted in view = {{ today | date:"dd-MM-y" }}</p>

<p>Date Formatted in Controller = {{date}}</p>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope,$filter) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
    $scope.date = $filter('date')($scope.today, "dd-MM-yyyy"); 
});
</script>

<p>The date filter formats a date object to a readable format.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**PLEASE RUN THE ABOVE SNIPPET**

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/s5923ww3JSlIcQ8eufXK?p=preview)