# how to filter json date formate in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, json

Any one tell me how to filter date from json date format. I want to disply like eg,wed, 07 Mar 2018.

My code is,

```
  <p>{{item.date}}</p>
```

my json is,

```
  "date": "Wed, 07 Mar 2018 00:00:00 PST",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs)

Comment: Have you try to search before asking? This question has been solved dozens of times.

Answer (score 2):

Apply a date filter with your requirements for the format:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
  var json = {
    "date": "Wed, 07 Mar 2018 00:00:00 PST"
  };
  $scope.item = new Date(json.date);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">
  <p>{{ item | date: 'dd MMM y'}}</p>
</div>
```

Note that you need to cast a date type to it first: `new Date()`

Answer (score 0):

use pipe "|" here is the link to the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the angularjs filter date passing the correct format, in your case the format is 'dd MMM yyyy'.

```
 <p>{{item.date | date: 'dd MMM yyyy'}}</p>
```

And also you have to transform your date in a valid javascript address:

```
$scope.item.date =  new Date($scope.item.date);
```

Comment: his json contains a **string**, which is not a valid date object, so the filter will not do anything by itself