# Change the date format after user enters the date using angularJs and js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, datepicker

```
<input class="cal" ng-model="mycalendar" mobiscroll-calendar="settings"
       mobiscroll-instance="demo" placeholder="Please Select..." />
```

[image]

I have an input box as above.I need the Date in 1960-04-30 00:00:00.000  format once the user selects the date from the picker

Comment: can you show the example of time string that you are getting right now?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_date.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs

Comment: You can always use `${date.getFullYear()}/${date.getMonth() +1}/${date.getDate()}`
or use momentjs

Comment: Using `moment.js` is more effective. It provides many functionalities.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format date in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392328/how-to-format-date-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dateInputVal = document.getElementById("yourElementId").value;
var d = new Date(dateInputVal);
var dt = d.getFullYear()+"/";
var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
if(m < 10)
    dt += "0"+m+"/";
else
    dt += m+"/";
var d2 = d.getDate();
if(d2 < 10)
    dt += "0"+d2;
else
    dt += d2;
```