# jquery date formatting, different for each browser?

Tags: javascript, datetime, formatting

I am calculating the date using the number of seconds since epoch at UTC.

here is how I am currently doing it:

```
var LastUpdatedTime = data.LastUpdated;
myDate = new Date(1000 * LastUpdatedTime);                                  
var LastUpdatedTime = myDate.toLocaleString();
```

In Chrome i see:
2/26/2013 9:57:35 AM

Which is exactly what I want

In Safari I see:
February 26, 2013 9:27:34 AM EST

Any advice on how to get Safari to format the date the same way Chrome does?

Comment: Build the string by hand. `toLocaleString()` does just what it says--it formats the string according to the user's locale (and apparently Safari uses a different locale) so you can't predict what its output will be.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427204/date-parsing-in-javascript-is-different-between-safari-and-chrome

Comment: you could try using this library http://zetafleet.com/blog/javascript-dateparse-for-iso-8601 with new Date. May do what you require

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/)

It gives you ways to nicely format days the way you want 
for example

```
   new Date().toString('dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are free to implement Date's string output functions in any format they like. To achieve a consistent format across browsers you will have to either create your own formatting function or use a third-party library such as [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) or [date.format.js](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format).

By the way, this has nothing to do with jQuery. The problem is that ECMAScript does not define a consistent date formatting mechanism.