# Date parse issue in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server, json, json.net

I'm getting values in datatable having a column of type DateTime.
After that I'm serializing it using `Json.Net`.

```
jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datatable);
```

Date in the datatable was: `2013-04-03 04:01:24.623`
Which after serialization stored in `jsonData` as: `2013-04-03T04:01:24.623`

On my page, I'm using it as:

```
timeStamp = new Date(jsonRow.TimeStamp).toLocaleString(); // Here jsonRow.TimeStamp is extracted from the received json response.
```

In `Safari`, browser, it gives error: `Invalid Date`.

Comment: I think [this][1] may help with your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427204/date-parsing-in-javascript-is-different-between-safari-and-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a similar Problem with an accepted Solution [Date parsing in javascript is different between safari and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427204/date-parsing-in-javascript-is-different-between-safari-and-chrome)

i hope this helps :)