# Javascript String to Date works in Chrome, not FF or Safari

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, safari

I have an element that shows a date string in this format:
    `<div> ListDate: 2014-11-22 00:00:00.0 </div>`
I have a variable that captures that text, now I am stripping out all but the date string and trying to convert it to a date so I can do some math on it. My code works fine in Chrome, but always returns NaN in FF and Safari. Here is the javascript:

```
var listDate = " ListDate: 2014-11-22 00:00:00.0 ";
listDate = listDate.replace('ListDate:', '');
listDate = $.trim(listDate);
listDate = Date.parse(listDate);
```

I'm watching it in Firebug, and it performs as expected up until Date.parse(). I tried the solutions shown on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427204/date-parsing-in-javascript-is-different-between-safari-and-chrome), but still no luck. Any ideas? I don't have control over the html, it comes from a web service.

Comment: The full ISO8601 format (IIRC) is expecting a capital letter "T" in between the date and time portions of that string.

Comment: Brilliant! I added `.replace(' ','T')` right after my trim method, she works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome!... I would have coded this as an answer but I'm between meetings on an iPhone :-(

Comment: @scunliffe you should move your comment into an answer for Gary D to accept !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full ISO8601 format (IIRC) is expecting a capital letter "T" in between the date and time portions of that string, e.g. ""2014-11-22**T**00:00:00.0"" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601 (I'd therefore recommend always adding the **T** delimiter.

E.g. the following code will parse to **NaN** in some browsers:

```
var myAlmostISODate = "2014-11-22 00:00:00.0";
console.log("Date: " + Date.parse(myAlmostISODate));
//IE11: NaN
//Firefox: 1416632400000
//Chrome: 1416632400000
```