# Date.parse showing error

Tags: javascript, datejs

I am using Date.js to parse string of Date and Time

```
var start_time='10-Jun-15 12:00 am';
var end_time='10-Jun-15 12:00 pm';
```

when alerts

```
alert(Date.parse(start_time)); 
alert(Date.parse(end_time));
```

the first one shows

```
 Wed Jun 10 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

and the second one shows

```
null
```

how to solve this?.thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine for me, are you sure thats what you tried?

Comment: instead of Date.parse why you don't try `new Date(start_time)`

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use quotation marks?

Comment: yes the same problem exists.

Comment: I am using jquery DateTime Picker to select the date and time.but this shows null only in the case of 12:00 pm

Comment: Make a fiddle that reproduces the problem with a jquery picker. I suppose you provide Date literals from screen: how Picker displays them. Not from debug when you can read actual picker value

Comment: Are you sure you should be using a library that hasn't been touched in 7 years and has minimal (almost zero) documentation? And yes, `Date.parse('10-Jun-15 12:00 PM')` returns *null* but `am` returns a valid Date.

Comment: Please refer [Date parsing in javascript is different between safari and chrome]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427204/date-parsing-in-javascript-is-different-between-safari-and-chrome

Comment: @RobG ,I am using that old js.How to solve this

Comment: @SachinIngale—the OP is using Datejs, which replaces the native *Date.parse*, so differences between native implementations aren't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

I've checked your date format in both chrome and FF. Firefox doesn't understand that format, but in chrome it works fine.

I used '10 Jun 2015 12:00 pm' format and it worked fine in both browsers.

So you should probably try removing dashes and use full year or use any other date format.

The date should be in [RFC2822 or ISO 8601](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) date format.

Answer (score 0):

The defect you describe occurs for me too in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. Rather than fix the library, here's a simple function to parse your date format. The 2 digit years are not a good idea, the function treats them as +2000. Three and four digit years are treated as is.

```
// Parse date format dd-mmm-yy hh:mm ap
// Two digit years are treated as 2000
// Years of three digits or more are treated as is
function parseDmY(s) {
  var months = {jan:0,feb:1,mar:2,apr:3,may:4,jun:5,
                jul:6,aug:7,sep:8,oct:9,nov:10,dec:11};
  var b = s.split(/[- :]/);
  var h = (b[3]%12) + (/pm/i.test(b[5])? 12 : 0);
  var y = +b[2] + (b[2] < 100? 2000 : 0)
  return new Date(y, months[b[1].toLowerCase()], b[0], h, b[4]);
}

console.log(parseDmY('10-Jun-2015 12:00 pm'));
```

Two digit years can also be treated by framing within a range of say -70 to +30 of the current year.

Answer (score 0):

If your date string is always provided in that format, using `Date.parseExact` will solve the problem... and it's more efficient than using `Date.parse`.

**Example**

```
var start_time='10-Jun-15 12:00 am';
var end_time='10-Jun-15 12:00 pm';

alert(Date.parseExact(start_time, 'dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt'));
alert(Date.parseExact(end_time, 'dd-MMM-yy hh:mm tt'));
```

Hope this helps.