# Javascript Date object issue in safari browser

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

I have a JavaScript code which is breaking in safari browser only. Here is the code..

```
var dateString = seldateCom.getFullYear()+"-"+month+"-"+seldateCom.getDate()+" "+$(this).val();
console.log("dateString = "+ dateString);
var date = new Date(Date.parse(dateString, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(date);
```

this is showing below error in safari browser console[image: Safari browser]

while in Chrome it is working perfectly, here is a screenshot of Chrome browser.[image]

What adjustment need to be done in order to work in both browsers?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6427318/7053190

Comment: in my case, can you write down code for me, which will remove this error in Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Date.parse` will not work in safari. To get around with this you can change the code to avoid the use of it:

```js
var dateString = "2019-3-6 05:30 pm";
var splitDate = dateString.split(/[^0-9]/);
var date = new Date(
splitDate[0],
splitDate[1]-1,
splitDate[2],
splitDate[3],
splitDate[4]
);
console.log('dateString', dateString);
console.log('date', date);
```